# Speech-to-text on Adobe Media Server 5.0.7

Tags: speech-to-text, adobe-media-server

We have a web application steam video into Adobe Media Server 5.0.7 which is hosted on AWS, then a mechanism pick up the videos and transcode the f4v files into different video formats and then store on S3.

We would like to implement some sort of speech-to-text mechanism on the videos recorded for analysis. I have found the following section on "https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/tech-overview/streaming-media.html"

> You now deliver Adobe Extensible Metatdata Platform (XMP) metadata embedded
>   video streaming through Adobe Media Server to Flash Player. XMP is a
>   labeling technology that allows you to embed data about a file into
>   the file itself. XMP metadata is a system that communicates critical
>   media information from the point where the media is created to the
>   point where media is viewed. With XMP, applications and publishing
>   systems can capture, share, and leverage metadata. In Adobe Media
>   Server, all the metadata embedded within a media file is accurately
>   delivered. In addition, speech-to-text metadata embedded within files
>   and encoded from Adobe Media Encoder CS4 can be delivered.

Can someone please point me to a direction on how to make it happen on Adobe Media Server?

Comment: You'd better use a custom tool for speech-to-text. Generic solutions with good accuracy are not yet available, you often need to build specialized platforms for different accents or noises.